# Conditional statement using two raster in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, raster

I am trying to create this grid "*To divide the population grid into two segments: (A) population with lighting detected, and (B) population with no lighting detected*". I have two raster data, a population.tif and a nighttimelights.tif. Basically, I want to meet two conditions:

population > 1 and nighttimelights > 20, this is segment A
population > 1 and nighttimelights < 20, this is segment B
I want to create the conditional statement in R. What I have tried so far is:

```
    library(raster)
    
    ntl = raster("path/ntl_atprk.tif")
    
    pop = raster("path/pop.tif")  
    
    pop = resample(pop, ntl, method = 'bilinear')
    
    if('pop' > 1 && 'ntl' >= 20) {
      *make the pop.tif raster's cell = 1*
    }
if('pop' > 1 && 'ntl' < 20) {
      *make the pop.tif raster's cell = 2*
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `terra::ifel` for that.

Example data

```
library(terra)
set.seed(0)
ntl <- rast(nrow=50, ncol=20, val=sample(40, 1000, replace=TRUE))
pop <- rast(nrow=50, ncol=20, val=sample(0:10, 1000, replace=TRUE))
```

Solution

```
x <- ifel(pop <= 1, NA, 
       ifel(ntl >= 20, 1, 2))
```

You did not specify what you would like to do with cells that have `pop <= 1`. I have assumed that you want to assign `NA` to these cells

Here is an alternative approach that achieves the same for these data

```
 pm <- pop > 1
 nm <- ntl < 20
 y <- mask(pm + nm, pm, maskvalue=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(raster)

ntl = raster("path/ntl_atprk.tif")
vals_ntl=as.data.frame(values(ntl)) #place the raster values to a data.frame

pop = raster("path/pop.tif")  
pop = resample(pop, ntl, method = 'bilinear')
vals_pop= as.data.frame(values(pop))#place the raster values to a data.frame

ntlpop =  as.data.frame(cbind(vals_pop, vals_ntl))#combine the 2 data.frames

ntlpop = na.omit(ntlpop) #remove the NA rows

ntlpopl = as.list(ntlpop) #convert the combine data.frame into a list


for (i in 1:lengths(ntlpopl)){
  if (ntlpopl[[1]][i] >= 1.0 && ntlpopl[[2]][i] >= 20.0 ) {
    
    ntlpopl[[1]][i] = 1
    
  } else if (ntlpopl[[1]][i] >= 1.0 && ntlpopl[[2]][i] < 20.0 ) {
    ntlpopl[[1]][i] = 0
  }
  else if(ntlpopl[[1]][i] < 1.0) {
    as.null(ntlpopl[[1]][i])
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Do not hesitate to add some comments explaining why your proposed code works so that the author and future readers will understand easily.

Thank you